# Cannot start GUI in CentOS in VirtualBox

Tags: centos, virtualbox

Using CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1611.iso I install it as guest vm on VirtualBox.

At first boot, the GUI isn't starting, only gives this:

[image]

**Q:** is it a bug? Or an extra setting?

Vbox version is: VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.12_112440_el6-1.x86_64 on a RHEL6 host. host HW is a T430.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

interesting.. two things helped:

1) Intel VT-d was disabled in the BIOS, ENABLE it! (this solved the GUI problem for the Ubuntu guest, but not CentOS)

2) Set the audio for the vbox guest centos to "ALSA Audio Driver" with "Intel HD Audio"

I don't know how the hell audio is related to the GUI.. but this solved it..

Answer (score 0):

Linux distributions can start and stop the graphical desktop in various ways. The exact method differs from distribution and among distribution versions. For the newer systemd-based distributions, the display manager is run as a service, you can stop the GUI desktop with the systemctl utility and most distributions will also work with the telinit command, as in:
$ sudo systemctl stop gdm (or sudo telinit 3)
First check the status : $sudo systemctl status gdm
It shooukd say inactive and then try below command it worked for me!
and restart it (after logging into the console) with:
***TRY***

```
$ sudo systemctl start gdm (or sudo telinit 5)
```